# GWT: Parse CSS style attribute

Tags: java, css, gwt, client

I am using gwt to create a table where i add some borders. Fx

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(cellElement, "border-left", "solid");
DOM.setStyleAttribute(cellElement, "border-right", "double");
...
```

Different browsers then sets the styling very differently. Especially the border property. It could be

```
border-left: solid 1px;
border-right: double 2px;
```

or

```
border-style-left: solid;
border-width-left: 1px;
border-style-right: double;
border-width-left: 2px;
```

or even as a single property

```
border: solid none double none;
...
```

Is the some way that these different ways of writing the same could be parsed, so that it would be easier to find border properties of a table. Something like:

```
border-left: solid;
border-top: none;
border-right: double;
border-bottom: none;
border-width-left: 1px;
border-width-top: 1px;
...
```

And the parsing should be done on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`currentStyle / getComputedStyle()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) will help with that, as long as the element has already been rendered.  You'll need to write a JSNI method to access it, since there doesn't appear to be an API wrapper for this in the DOM package.